# R- regex extracting a string between a dash and a period

Tags: regex, r

First of all I apologize if this question is too naive or has been repeated earlier. I tried to find it in the forum but I'm posting it as a question because I failed to find an answer.

I have a data frame with column names as follows;

```
head(rownames(u))

[1] "A17-R-Null-C-3.AT2G41240"       "A18-R-Null-C-3.AT2G41240"         "B19-R-Null-C-3.AT2G41240"      
[4] "B20-R-Null-C-3.AT2G41240"       "A21-R-Transgenic-C-3.AT2G41240" "A22-R-Transgenic-C-3.AT2G41240"
```

What I want is to use regex in R to extract the string in between the first dash and the last period.

Anticipated results are,

```
[1] "R-Null-C-3"       "R-Null-C-3"         "R-Null-C-3"      
[4] "R-Null-C-3"       "R-Transgenic-C-3" "R-Transgenic-C-3"
```

I tried following with no luck...

```
gsub("^[^-]*-|.+\\.","\\2", rownames(u))
gsub("^.+-","", rownames(u))
sub("^[^-]*.|\\..","", rownames(u))
```

Would someone be able to help me with this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Shani.

Comment: [`-([^.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/lC6hK6/1) - search for a dash, capture everything that is not a dot and save it to the first group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution to be used with `gsub`:

```
v <- c("A17-R-Null-C-3.AT2G41240", "A18-R-Null-C-3.AT2G41240", "B19-R-Null-C-3.AT2G41240", "B20-R-Null-C-3.AT2G41240", "A21-R-Transgenic-C-3.AT2G41240", "A22-R-Transgenic-C-3.AT2G41240")
gsub("^[^-]*-([^.]+).*", "\\1", v)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/cDr9VQ)

The [regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/tX4mI3/1):

- `^[^-]*` - zero or more characters other than `-`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([^.]+)` - Group 1 matching and capturing one or more characters other than a dot
- `.*` - any characters (even including a newline since `perl=T` is not used), any number of occurrences up to the end of the string.

Comment: Also one more thing. If understand what "\\1" does is replacing the found pattern with the value captured in group 1, meaning what is captured in the group 1 is retained but the rest is eliminated; am I correct? Thank you.

Comment: Absolutely correct. A pair of unescaped parentheses captures a part of the matched string into a separate memory buffer so that we could later get that substring using a back reference in the replacement pattern.

Answer (score 2):

### Regex

```
-([^.]+)\\.
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

### Description

```
- matches the character - literally
    1st Capturing group ([^\\.]+)
        [^\.]+ match a single character not present in the list below
            Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        . matches the character . literally
    \\. matches the character . literally
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/T5_NbQfMuK9tfJd3)

### Output

```
MATCH 1
1.  [4-14]  `R-Null-C-3`
MATCH 2
1.  [29-39] `R-Null-C-3`
MATCH 3
1.  [54-64] `R-Null-C-3`
MATCH 4
1.  [85-95] `R-Null-C-3`
MATCH 5
1.  [110-126]   `R-Transgenic-C-3`
MATCH 6
1.  [141-157]   `R-Transgenic-C-3`
```

Comment: No need to escape the dot in square brackets.

Comment: R regex requires double literal escaping, anyway: `\\.`

Comment: Thank you. This also gives me the result as what it gives from Jan though. However, I'm sure it will be helpful in the future. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be achieved with the following regex:

```
-([^.]+)
# look for a dash
# then match everything that is not a dot
# and save it to the first group
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lC6hK6/1). Outputs are:

```
R-Null-C-3
R-Null-C-3
R-Null-C-3
R-Null-C-3
R-Transgenic-C-3
R-Transgenic-C-3
```

Comment: `v <-  c("A17-R-Null-C-3.AT2G41240", "A18-R-Null-C-3.AT2G41240", "B19-R-Null-C-3.AT2G41240", "B20-R-Null-C-3.AT2G41240", "A21-R-Transgenic-C-3.AT2G41240", "A22-R-Transgenic-C-3.AT2G41240")`;
`gsub("-([^.]+)", '' , v)`

gives me following as the results;

`"A17.AT2G41240" "A18.AT2G41240" "B19.AT2G41240" "B20.AT2G41240" "A21.AT2G41240" "A22.AT2G41240"`

Not exactly what I'm looking for, but will surely be helpful in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This seems an appropriate case for [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(v, '(?<=-).*(?=\\.)')
```

where

- `(?<= ... )` is a *positive lookbehind*, i.e. it looks for a `-` immediately before the next captured group;
- `.*` is any character `.` repeated 0 or more times `*`;
- `(?= ... )` is a *positive lookahead*, i.e. it looks for a period (escaped as `\\.`) following what is actually captured.

I used `stringr::str_extract` above because it's more direct in terms of what you're trying to do. It is possible to do the same thing with `sub` (or `gsub`), but the regex has to be uglier:

```
sub('.*?(?<=-)(.*)(?=\\.).*', '\\1', v, perl = TRUE)
```

- `.*?` looks for any character `.` from 0 to as few as possible times `*?` (lazy evaluation);
- the lookbehind `(?<=-)` is the same as above;
- now the part we want `.*` is put in a captured group `(...)`, which we'll need later;
- the lookahead `(?=\\.)` is the same;
- `.*` captures any character, repeated 0 to as many as possible times (here the end of the string).
- The replacement is `\\1`, which refers to the first captured group from the pattern regex.

Comment: There is no need using a capturing group since you are using lookarounds to extract a *match*, not a *capture* (you'd want to use `str_match` then). I'd recommend against using lookaround based regex since the lookbehind is rather a costly construct in terms of performance.